# The argument types 'Edm.String' and 'Edm.Int32' are incompatible for this operation

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am getting the error like above tag which will be at the place of

> return View(st.employees.Find(id));

above place only ,can any one help me from this! and my code is

```
     namespace StartApp.Controllers
  {
public class EmployController : Controller
{
    StartEntities st = new StartEntities();
    //List
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return View(st.employees.ToList());
    }
    //Details
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        return View(st.employees.Find(id));
    }
    //Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
       return View();
    }


    [HttpPost,ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(employee e)
    {
        using(st)
        {
            st.employees.Add(e);
            try
            {
                st.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
           {
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Here is an error");
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
   //edit
    public  ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {

           return View(st.employees.Find(id));

    }

    [HttpPost,ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(employee e)
    {
        st.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
        st.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
    //Delete
    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        return View(st.employees.Find(id));
    }
    [HttpPost,ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult Delete_conf(int id)
    {
        employee emp = st.employees.Find(id);
           st.employees.Remove(emp);
           st.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("List");
    }

}
```

}

can any one help me to rectify that error!

Comment: Take a look at `Employee` entity. What is the type of its `Key`?

Comment: it's primary key only

Comment: What's the data type of key in your class. (Look at properties of the field in edmx or your code files)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exception usually happens when your entities primary key is of type A and you are passing a variable which is not of type A to the `Find` method.

From the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) of `Find` method, It may throw the below exception

> **InvalidOperationException**
>
> Thrown if the types of the key values do not match the types of the
>   key values for the entity type to be found.

Make sure you use the same type variable when you call the `Find` method.

In your code, you are passing an integer variable to the `Find` method. From the error i believe your entity classes primary key is not int type. May be it is `Guid` type, in that case, make sure you are passing a valid Guid value to the `Find` method.

You can open up the edmx file and see the type of your key and make sure you pass the same type to the `Find` method.

Just right click on the entity in your edmx file and select properties.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , i am new to mvc. May i know what is type A.

Comment: It can be any type (Ex : Guid ). In your code you are passing an int variable. Check your entity class in edmx file to see what type it is

Comment: yes, i am not declaring it as int. i am declared as varchar(50) .Now what value i will pass instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are following the MVC pattern.

I got this error as well and it is because I was passing the id parameter as an integer instead of "string" as I declared in my model.

Sample:

```
public class Object
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string property1{ get; set; }
    public string property2{ get; set; }
    public string property3{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Find()` will only accept parameter with datatype similar to primary key of table for which you are going to use `Find()`.