# How to update multiple entities with file import in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have a table with user data. I call it 'clients'.
I want to import an excel file where I have more data for them, phone number address etc.

My controller looks like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {


                string email = row["email"].ToString();

                Clients clients = db.Clients.Find(email);
                var lea = this.db.Clients.Find(email.ToString());
                clients.PromoCode = row["AFF"].ToString();
                clients.workerId = Convert.ToInt16(row["workersid"]);
                clients.Rentetiion = Convert.ToInt16(row["Rentetiion"]);
                clients.Contof = row["login"].ToString();
                clients.Company = row["Company"].ToString();
                clients.Phone = row["Phone"].ToString();
                db.Entry(clients).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
db.savechanges
```

I want to filter by email and update the data on the database, but I get this error:

```
The argument types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38833108/1080354

Comment: i am passing a string form the email.